# How to write an x86 Intel assembly code to make a 9x9 grid?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, x86-16

How can I write an x86 intel assembly code to make a 9x9 grid. this will eventually be Sudoku board?

I have no clue what I'm doing since I'm so new to this. I tried multiple codes but have trouble running them. My plan is to use the 194, 196, 197, 217, 218, 192, 170, 196, etc to make the table. My main issue is that I cont print out the extended ASCII codes.

```
.model small
.data

.code
main proc
 mov dl,0xB3
 mov ah, 2h ;code to print
 int 21h    

endp

end main
```

When I run this code, it's supposed to print a straight line (I think the code for the line is 179) but it prints nothing.

Comment: Does this actually assemble?  I'd expect that you can either use `2h` to specific a hex number or `0xb3`.  Using both in the same code seems odd.

Comment: Under which OS are you attempting to run this?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: NASM accepts both `0x0` and `0h`.  Many other assemblers only accept one or the other.  This looks like MASM, which last I heard only supported `0h`.  [How to represent hex value such as FFFFFFBB in x86 inline assembly programming?](//stackoverflow.com/a/37152498).  But presumably it's something else with the same directives (possibly TASM).  According to my answer, FASM also supports both `0h` and `0x0`, but IDK if it uses MASM/TASM directives.  OP, please clarify exactly how you're building and running this code.  (Inside DOSBOX?)

Comment: i am running on windows. guys as i said i have absolutely no idea what im doing. my professor is very bad and dont really have time to learn the whole course because of its due in a few days. i just need to know (1) how to print the 128-255 characters from the ascii table and (2)  how to add spaces in the same line (so that i can add columns) and (3) how to go to a new line

Comment: i didnt know how to turn 179 to a hex so i googled it and it gave me 0xB3. my professor usually use numbers and letters but i dont know how to convert

Comment: DOS `int 21h` doesn't work in a normal Windows PE (32-bit) executable [x86 assembly (masm32) - Can I use int 21h on windows xp to print things?](//stackoverflow.com/q/10583657).  You have to run 16-bit DOS code in a special environment.

Comment: You can `mov dl, 179` and let the assembler do the conversion for you!  All assemblers (except `debug.exe`) support your choice of hex or decimal for numeric literals, just like C.   Or use any hex<->decimal conversion program if you don't want to do the math on paper.

Comment: your small program is not printing "nothing", it prints a single sign (' | ') , and then (because you don't return to DOS using int 21/4c) starts to execute the (random) code that's following yours.

Comment: `mov ah,48` is equal to `mov ah,30h` and that is equal to `mov ah,'0'` and all of them will produce same binary machine code, because the computer can store only binary information encoded in bit values (0 or 1). The final machine code doesn't contain any information, if the value 48 was in source written as decimal, hexadecimal or ASCII letter, it will just end in the `mov ah, immediate_8bit_constant` instruction opcode as 8 bit constant encoded as `0011_0000` sequence of bits. So you don't need to convert 179 to anything. Although you should be able to convert it to hexa from head/on paper.

Comment: And as you don't understand even such basics, not sure what your course is, but if it was about computer architecture and assembly basics, I would demand a refund (or you should seriously revise your own effort). If it's due in couple of days, even better, rather fail early, than wasting everyone else's time.

Comment: Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.